# Add text when no result

Tags: php, wordpress

I have to customize a function.
That fonction display custom posts on a (custom) category page.
The problem of this function concerns the absence of text when there is no results.

For instance, on any category page, if there is no available post to show in the grid, I would like to display a text such as "There is no post in this category. Please try another category."

Here is the code:

```
 

        global $paged, $wp_query, $wp;
        $args = wp_parse_args($wp->matched_query);
        if ( !empty ( $args['paged'] ) && 0 == $paged ) {
        $wp_query->set('paged', $args['paged']);
        $paged = $args['paged'];
        }                           
        $cat_id = get_queried_object_id();
        $temp = $wp_query;
        $featuredPosts = array();
        $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => $classieraFeaturedAdsCounter,
        'paged' => $paged,                              
        'cat' => $cat_id,
        'meta_query' => array(
        array(
        'key' => 'featured_post',
        'value' => '1',
        'compare' => '=='
                             )
            ),
        );
        $wp_query= null;
        $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
        while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();
        $featuredPosts[] = $post->ID;
        get_template_part( 'templates/classiera-loops/loop-ivy');
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
        wp_reset_query();
```

Does anyone has an idea to include this option?
Thanks.

SOLUTION:

```
    wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
    if ( have_posts() ) :
    while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();
    $featuredPosts[] = $post->ID;
    get_template_part( 'templates/classiera-loops/loop-ivy');
    endwhile;
    else :
    echo wpautop('No result');
    endif;
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Right now it is just your query which will only output something if you got posts. Please show something you tried to solve this problem, what you expected it to do and what it actually did. Also: Have you tried to google something like "wp query get total post count"? If so, you should have a link to the official Wordpress documentation, which shows WP_Query has a field which you can access exactly for this purpose.

Comment: Also, we have a dedicated [Wordpress SE](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @TobiasF.: it's not task for wordpress but basic PHP condition.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a WP developer, but it seems to be

```
if ($wp_query->have_posts()) {
    while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();
} else {
    echo 'No post here';
}
```

Reference link : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/have_posts

Comment: Not sure where to copy this code... since everything I tried has a blank page as result... :/

Comment: @user3301061 basically wrap everything between `while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();` and `endwhile;` with the if statement of this answer: `if ($wp_query->have_posts())`.

Comment: @user3301061: change line `while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();` (6th form bottom) with lines I wrote.